# why can't I include a picture, why do I an error occurred. forbidden?

Tags: support

I would upload a pic showing the problem.  But I can't.  Seems like I have never been able to.
When I try to, I get **An error occurred when uploading the image: Forbidden**.
What's the deal, is it forbidden in all around if so why offer it, or is it just me that's forbidden if so why?

Comment: I didn't find anything relevant on Meta.SE, and I've never heard of an account being unable to upload an image. Just to be sure, are you using the image upload icon in the editor tool? And then you click Browse to find a local file?

Comment: yes browse to find a local file, I choose *something.jpg* that is 100kb on my desktop.  Never works or has never worked for me.

Comment: is it possible some admin punished me by preventing my account from uploading a picture?

Comment: I suppose it's *possible*, but I have no idea how it would be implemented. I don't think any of the U&L moderators requested it.  If someone (staff) at SE did it, they didn't let us in on it. I'd recommend using the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page to explain what you're seeing, and hopefully someone can get to the bottom of it. I'd be curious to hear, myself!

Comment: Can you try using a different browser, just in case? I've never heard of anything like this, so I suspect it might be an issue on your side.

Comment: @ron have you made any progress on this, with a different browser or with a Help ticket?

Comment: i keep forgetting to try at home, with a different browser

Comment: So let's remind you from time to time (-;

Comment: yeah, keep reminding me :)  maybe tonight

Comment: Could tonight be the night? :P

Answer (score 1):

remembered to try and post a pic...

[image]

works on my home pc, firefox 116.0.3
gotta be some restriction at work.
you can close this.

Comment: Glad you (sort of?!?) got to the bottom of it. It sounds likely that a work-based firewall is blocking an important piece of the picture-upload process for you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the network you are using is blocking Imgur. This is pretty common with "category/tag-based" site filters (I'm not sure what the proper term is).

According a few "URL Category Checkers" ([Cyren](https://www.cyren.com/security-center/url-category-check-gate), [zveloLIVE](https://tools.zvelo.com/), [Paloalto](https://urlfiltering.paloaltonetworks.com/query/)) I found Imgur is categorized as "Image Sharing", "Photo Sharing", and "Online-Storage-and-Backup" respectively.

There may be several reasons why these categories are blocked. Some may include wanting to block the sharing of files, or these categories being a subset of "Social Media". The latter reason is kind of half-true because Imgur can be used that way despite mostly being used for image hosting, though I don't know what anyone would want to do that.

In any case, that seems to be the most likely reason since you are able to access StackExchange but not upload pictures.